# Add Time in Calendar By Getting the User input

Tags: android, calendar, datetime-format

Can you help on adding time using calendar method? In my layout I have a clock and sorrounds by numbers each number are setOnTouchListener. What I want to do is this if user tap on each number it will add 10 hours. e.g When user touch on number 1 so the time  would become 11.

If there's other way please show it to me how.Thanks

Here's my activity code

```
String timeOut = "2:00";//set the time
int time1 = Integer.parseInt(timeOut); //converting the string into integer 

Calendar cld = cld.getInstance();
cld.add(Calendar.HOUR, 10); //in this line here I want to add the variable time1

tetxtView.setText("You added time is equal to " + cld.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

from what you are saying, I understand that the user clicked on 2 so, you need to display 12.

so just add 10 + time1 = 10+2 = 12.

```
String timeOut = "2:00";//set the time
int time1 = Integer.parseInt(timeOut);

Calendar cld = cld.getInstance();
cld.add(Calendar.HOUR, 10 + time1); //in this line here I want to add the variable time1
```

now you will see , 12 as your time.

let me know if this solves your prob..

Comment: Please comment how to output this one. I try to add a toast but its not working the application leads to a force close. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

```
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = sdf.parse("12:22");
        System.out.println("Date "+date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
    System.out.println("Calendar hour "+ sdf.format(calendar.getTime())); //Just format it as i have added this line
```

Comment: This is working fine but the output says Thu Jan 01 22:22:00 GMT 1970. I want to display only the time. Can you please help me?

Comment: Yes, i have edited my answer and just replace last line .It is formatting the time , so it will give just time in your desired format

Comment: How to add period in time. Using this code. Can you help me?

Comment: I don't understand what u want to say.Meaning of period in this context

Comment: Period means the interval of time.In my application I have clock sorrounds by numbers and each numbers are setOntouchListener. Now, if the user tap on 2 it will add 10 hours and became 12 Hours. When it will became 12 Hours there is a period or time interval of 10 to 12 Hours now I want to do is to add another set of interval between 10 to 12. In other words I want a back to back 10 to 12 hours time interval. Can you help on this..